# How to get the class name of a derived class when executing a static method in the base class?

Tags: c#, .net

In the following I would like a call to MyOtherClass.MyStaticMethod() to output "MyOtherClass", is this possible? All my current attempts give me "MyClass".

The issue I have is that I can't easily change MyOtherClass, since there are 100s of classes which extend from MyClass.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string MyStaticMethod()
    {
        string className = typeof(MyClass).Name;
        Console.WriteLine(className);
    }
}
public class MyOtherClass : MyClass{ }
```

Comment: You can abuse generics to get this.  I don't recommend it.  Link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/1cb74fe7-dfc8-45c0-8ad4-34e4c6e990c9

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need it to be an instance method, then call

```
string className = typeof(this).Name;
```

Comment: it needs to be static, since its not viable to create an instance of MyOtherClass just to call the MyStatic method

Comment: That's why I said make it an instance method!

Answer (score 1):

In C# and Java you can **overload** a static method, but not **override** it. That is, polymorphism and inheritance on static method does not exists. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods/2223408#2223408) for more detail)

There is not concept of `this` on static method, and as a consequence, you can not get the type in a polymorphic way. Which means that you would need to define one static method per class in a way to print the right type.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat related to a question I just asked last week: [C# static member “inheritance” - why does this exist at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281775/c-static-member-inheritance-why-does-this-exist-at-all).

To cut to the chase, **C# doesn't really support static method inheritance** - so, you can't do what you ask.  Unfortunately, it is possible to write `MyOtherClass.MyStaticMethod()` - but that doesn't mean there's any real inheritance going on: under the covers this is just the scoping rules being very lenient.

**Edit:**  Although you can't do this directly, you can do what C++ programmers call a [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern) and get pretty close with generics<sup>[[1]](http://www.linqpad.net/)</sup>:

```
public class MyClass<TDerived> where TDerived:MyClass<TDerived> {
    public static string MyStaticMethod() { return  typeof(TDerived).Name; }
}
public class MyOtherClass : MyClass<MyOtherClass> { }
public class HmmClass:MyOtherClass { }

void Main() {
    MyOtherClass.MyStaticMethod().Dump(); //linqpad says MyOtherClass
    HmmClass.MyStaticMethod().Dump();  //linqpad also says MyOtherClass
}
```

Here, you do need to update the subclass - but only in a minor fashion.

Comment: However, this is a major code change as the OP specifies that there are "are 100s of classes which extend from MyClass".

Comment: Yep, but it's simpler than any other alternative I could come up with - and the compiler can help you here, as adding the generic type parameter will mean that any non-generic reference to MyClass will be invalid.  I've done this kind of refactoring before (for probably more than a 1000 references) - it's mind-numbing F8 for next error, go fix, etc, but it's just a days work, at worst.

Comment: And in this case, a regex might actually automatically fix all compile errors; simply replace `^{.*class {.*}.* : .* }MyClass{.*}$` with `\1MyClass<\2>\3` in VS.NET's wonky syntax (or some similar such search).

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 3.5 of the .NET framework you could use an extension function to retrieve the information about the instance of the class.

```
public static class MyClassExtensions {
  public static string Name(this MyClass instance) {
    return typeof(instance).Name;
  }
}
```

Provides an instance method without modifying the definition of MyOtherClass.

Comment: The OP is trying to specialize static methods - and then this won't work.