# object oriented: is it possible use a static instance like a variable?

Tags: c#

I think I couldnt do this thing, but I try to ask (maybe :)).

Suppose I have this Main class :

```
public class UiUtils
{   
    public static MyObject myObject;
    public UiUtils()
    {
       myObject=new MyObject();
    }
}
```

now if I want to try to call this instance from another Context Class (web application), I do this :

```
public partial class context_eventi_CustomClass : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{   
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Console.Write(UiUtils.myObject.Title());
    }
}
```

but what I'd like to do is this :

```
public partial class context_eventi_CustomClass : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{   
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Console.Write(myObject.Title());
    }
}
```

so, use directly myObject and not UiUtils.myObject :)

I think this is not possible, but maybe I wrong and there are any strategies :) Thanks

** EDIT **

my solution for the moment :

```
public class UiUtils
{   
    public static MyObject myObject;
    public UiUtils()
    {
       myObject=new MyObject();
       iContext.myObject = myObject;
    }
}

public class iContext : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public static MyObject myObject;

    public iContext()
    {

    }    

    public iContext(MyObject myObject)
    {
        myObject = myObject;
    }
}

public partial class context_eventi_CustomClass : iContext
{   
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Console.Write(myObject.Title());
    }
}
```

seems to works! What do you think about?

Comment: did you mean you want to do: `Console.Write(myObject.Title());` as `myObject`'s instance in CustomClass.. ?

Comment: Yeah, use `myObject` and not `UiUtils.myObject`

Comment: Your current solution may work but doesn't make sense to do it that way just so you can skip typing a class name.  What is the problem with using the class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the object without typing the class you can use inheritance.

```
public class CustomClass : UiUtils
```

This will share UiUtils properties with CustomClass

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to write that my class extend already another class (: System.Web.UI.UserControl)

Comment: then make `UiUtils : UserControl` and `CustomClass : UiUtils`

Comment: Update the answer! Sorry I forgot a important details :)

Comment: I can't! UiUtils it's a "real" class :)

Comment: If you can't do inheritance then your probably going to have to stick with using the class name before the variable. What was the issue with using the class name?

Comment: @0A0D: How is this bad? I cant post comments yet, but your answer was wrong also.

Comment: @ZEAL: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281775/c-static-member-inheritance-why-does-this-exist-at-all

Comment: and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774181/why-cant-i-inherit-static-classes/774205#774205

Comment: He is talking about static variables not classes. And i know it doesn't make since to do this this way, but it does work there for it is not wrong.

Comment: @ZEAL: UiUtils is not static.

Answer (score 2):

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx),

> A static method, field, property, or
>   event is callable on a class even when
>   no instance of the class has been
>   created. **If any instances of the class**
>   are created, they cannot be used to
>   **access the static member.** Only one
>   copy of static fields and events
>   exists, and static methods and
>   properties can only access static
>   fields and static events. Static
>   members are often used to represent
>   data or calculations that do not
>   change in response to object state.

and

**"To access a static class member, use the name of the class instead of a variable name to specify the location of the member."**

and

> The static member is always accessed
>   by the **class name**, not the
>   instance name

@Daniel Earwicker says in his [answer on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281775/c-static-member-inheritance-why-does-this-exist-at-all):

> ...Static members fail to integrate
>   well with inheritance. It makes no
>   sense to have them heritable. So I
>   keep static things in separate static
>   classes...

So I am not clear on your design why MyObject needs to be static. All you are trying to save is a little typing, but inheritance will not help you here either.

Edit:

I tried to replicate your code in a simple console application. The output is not what you would expect:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class UiUtils
    {
        public static int myObject = 1;
        public UiUtils()
        {
            myObject = new int();
            iContext.myObject = myObject;
            Console.WriteLine("This is UiUtils\n");
        }
    }

    public class iContext
    {
        public static int myObject = 2;

        public iContext()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is iContext\n");
        }

        public iContext(int myObject)
        {
            myObject = myObject;
        }
    }

    public class iContext2 : iContext
    {
        public static int myObject = 3;

        public iContext2()
        {

            Console.WriteLine(myObject.ToString() + "\nThis is iContext2\n");
            Console.WriteLine(iContext.myObject.ToString());
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            iContext2 icontext = new iContext2();
            Console.In.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The output ends up being this:

```
This is iContext

3 
This is iContext2
```

If you add a call to iContext.myObject, then it outputs it's number:

```
This is iContext

3
This is iContext2
2
```

Comment: Added a solution! What do you think about?

Comment: @markzzz: You should make the example simpler and print to the console such as "This is class UiUtils", etc. That way you can watch how the classes are being called.

Comment: In fact it works on my web application! but maybe I can do better :)

Comment: @markzzz: look again. UiUtils is never called and the inheritance is not working like you wanted.

Comment: @markzzz: No you don't. You define it, but it is never called. I copied your example verbatim and made some slight changes but that's it.

Comment: UiUtils is called in my application as first class (ever). It create the instance of myObject, and pass it to iContext. Then, on other class (CustomClass) it extend iContext and get the right instance of myObject :) (im on a web application, with .NET, and a flux of operations. UiUtils will ever be called before any class)

Comment: You don't call here! But on my application it is called before other classes! :)

Comment: @markzzz: I can't help you if you don't post all your code or give me all the information. I am not a mind-reader.