# Hiding static variables/functions and using them in base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, static

I have a base class with a protected-level static variable, a protected-level static function, and a public function:

```
public class ClassA
{
    protected static int Size = 4;

    public static byte[] DoSomething(byte[] params)
    {
        // use Size somehow
        params = DoSomethingElse(params);
        return params;
    }

    protected static byte[] DoSomethingElse(byte[] params)
    {
        // do whatever
        return params;
    }
}
```

And a derived class that hides the protected-level variable and function:

```
public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public new static int Size = 2;

    protected new static byte[] DoSomethingElse(byte[] params)
    {
        // do something different than base class
        return params;
    }
}
```

Now, when I call ClassB.DoSomething, I want the Size value and DoSomethingElse from the ClassBto be used, but the ClassA values are used instead. Is there a way to make this use the ClassB variable and method?

Comment: what are you asking for is runtime polyorphism for static function...I dont think this is possible....

Comment: afaik Viru is correct and it isn't possible - consider for example if you subclass ClassB - what should Size then refer to in ClassC? I couldn't find the definitive answer in the C# spec but since static methods cannot be overridden (only overloaded) I am willing to bet a similar rule applies to static fields/properties

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281775/c-sharp-static-member-inheritance-why-does-this-exist-at-all