# What is the difference between these unicode classes?

Tags: .net

Say I wanted to convert a string into a utf8 byte array, I could do it via

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(...)
```

or

```
System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(...)
```

or

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(...)
```

As far as I can tell there is no difference between them. Are they all referring to the same thing? Why are there so many?

Comment: this is the same static property of `Encoding` base class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Both [`UnicodeEncoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.unicodeencoding.aspx) and [`UTF8Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.utf8encoding.aspx) are subclasses of the [`Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.encoding.aspx)
   class.
2. [`UTF8`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx) is a static property of the `Encoding` class
3. You can access a static property/field/method of a class by using the name of one of its subclasses, so that `UnicodeEncoding.UTF8` in this case is the same as writing `Encoding.UTF8`
4. As an exception to point 3, a subclass can "hide" a property/field/method of a subclass by using the `new` keyword... BUT this doesn't happen in this case.

For points 3 and 4 see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2281775/613130) (it is about a method, but the concept is the same)