# Why is this static instance of the parent shared between new instances of children?

Tags: c#, singleton

Given the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dog = new Dog();
        var cat = new Cat();

        dog.Print();
        cat.Print();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public abstract class Animal
{
    private static string _name;

    protected Animal(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    private static string _hi;
    private string SayHi()
    {
        return _hi ?? (_hi = $"Hi, i'm a {_name}!");
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{this.GetType().Name} says: {SayHi()}");
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat() : base("Cat")
    {
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog() : base("Dog")
    {
    }
}
```

The following output is produced:

> Dog says: Hi, i'm a Cat!
>
> Cat says: Hi, i'm a Cat!

Why? I would expect the Dog to say "Hi, i'm a Dog!"

Can someone a) explain to me this behaviour and b) let me know how i should update my code?

The real example is that i'm sharing an *expensive* property between concrete classes.

Comment: Remove `static` and made it `protected`. Static member not inheritable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# static member "inheritance" - why does this exist at all?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281775/c-sharp-static-member-inheritance-why-does-this-exist-at-all)

Comment: This makes perfect sense since static fields are actually members of a class, not an instance of a class. Hence, Dog and Cat which are objects will share those fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should become more familiar with `static` keyword. [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) could be helpful.

Fields or properties marked `static` are belongs to class itself but not to instances of this class. When you create new instance of `Dog` the field `_name` initializes with `"Dog"` string. But when you creates new instance of `Cat` the field `_name` changes its value for `"Cat"` string.

As `_name` belongs to base `Animal` class, every instance of descendant class will be referenced to the same value.

You should remove the `static` modifier, if you want to make `_name` belongs to instances of classes and not to class itself.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the answer. What if i want all instances of "Dog" to share the same property, and all instances of "Cat" to share their own property? How would i achieve that?

Comment: If you want to have an unique single value for all Dog instances and an unique single value for all Cat instances - you can set static fields both in Dog and Cat. Although application behaviour will not be different if you will remove static modifier. It allows you to use this field in a base class. The first case with static fields in both classes will not allow to do it, and will look as bad smell code. Maybe, you want to use attributes instead of static field?