# How to get Classes to expose the same Shared/Static method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, inheritance

I have a base class with several derived classes. I want all of my derived classes to have the same `Public Shared` (`static`) method with their own implementation. How do I do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: As noted by SO down the side of this question there are many similar questions, including this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380087/whats-the-correct-alternative-to-static-method-inheritance-c which has some further relevant answers.

Answer (score 2):

I know this seems like a useful feature *"at design time"* but imagine how this could be used:

If `GetForms` is `Shared` (`static` in C#) you don't have an object with a type to distinguish which method to use, i.e. you can't say `BaseForm.GetForms()` in some way that it can be determined which of `ChildFormTypeA.GetForms()` and `ChildFormTypeB.GetForms()` is actually called.

The best you can do is document this is the intention if you just want explicit calls to `ChildFormTypeA.GetForms()` and `ChildFormTypeB.GetForms()`, or if you really need the concept make it a factory method e.g.

```
MustInherit Class BaseForm

  MustOverride Sub GetForms()

End Class

Class MyForm
   Inherits BaseForm

   Public Sub New()
   End Sub

   Overrides Sub GetForms()
   End Sub   
End Class
```

Now you just need

```
Dim f as BaseForm = New MyForm
f.GetForms
```

Alternatively `GetForms` might be `Protected` and called from the `Sub New`.

---

*EDIT: This is almost a new answer.*

I have just needed this when maintaining existing code. I decided the simplest way to go was to make both classes implement an interface:

```
Interface ISharedNew
  Function SharedNew(ByVal Argument As String) As ISharedNew
End Interface
```

(In this case, I have an existing use of the classes via a generic constraint `T As New` and I needed the constructor to now have a parameter which generic constraints do not support.)

The new (simplified) generic code is now:

```
Function GetNew(Of T As {New, ISharedNew})(ByVal Argument As String) As T
  Return DirectCast((New T).SharedNew(Argument), T)
End Function
```

In my case, the `New T` object itself is ignored by the `SharedNew`, but its type does specify the relevant instance of `SharedNew`, which creates a new `T` object using the `Argument`.

*The code has been added to this answer from scratch, without referencing the actual code.*

Comment: Totally Agree. MyForm.GetForms() can operate only on the type MyForm and there is no way to specify the derived type form which need to be used.

Comment: It would be easy to distinguish, I would think, if I call something like `Invoice.GetForms()`, it would go to the shared 'GetForms()` method in the `Invoice` class... how is that difficult? In the base class, declare it as `Public MustOverride Shared Sub GetForms()`. Unfortunately, this won't compile... makes perfect sense to me that it should though...

Comment: @Jason, That's what I mean by it might as well just be documented as the intention: how is the code broken if the intended functionality was actually implemented by InvoiceOther.TheFormsGet().

Answer (score 0):

No.  You could use a singleton, but there may be a better design.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a static method cannot be declared as virtual.  To achieve this without static methods you would do something like the following:

```
public abstract class BaseFoo
{
    protected virtual void Bar()
    {
    }
}

public class Foo : BaseFoo
{
    protected override void Bar()
    {
        base.Bar();
    }
}
```

If you wanted to achieve something similar to having it as static you could use the singleton pattern so that you share a single instance of the object.

**Edit**:

I realized your original question talked about VB syntax, so here's the same thing in VB:

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseFoo

    Protected Overridable Sub Bar()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Foo
    Inherits BaseFoo

    Protected Overrides Sub Bar()
        MyBase.Bar()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: is there any reason for this? it seems stupid that you can't declare a static method sig that can be used across all classes.

Comment: RE: your edit - yep, thanks... i was able to convert it in my head, but yeah i'm working in vb for this project :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?  A virtual method relies on an instantiated object, whereas a static method exists without needing the object to be created.  That's why static methods can only reference other static variables/methods.

If it's simply the method signature you're trying to share, the example I gave before shows that the signature would get shared.  Without knowing your exact scenario here, I'd say you'd probably benefit from either the singleton pattern or dependency injection.

Comment: What I'm saying is that they do the same thing, but their implementation details require something slightly different. It would be perfect if I could declare `BaseForm.GetForms()` as `MustOverride` and just include the implementation details there, but I can't.