# C#: Type specific/static methods supporting overriding

Tags: c#, static, types, overriding

In C# it is not possible to override a static method. Nevertheless I have some type specific methods (instead of the usual instance methods) and I want to give the user the ability to override those methods, and in addition, have the ability to call those (overridden) methods from my own code without knowing about the 'overriding' done by the user. Would the method be static, I would have to know the type name of the user's class in advance, which is not what I want.

**How to implement type specific methods like `Read`, `Write` and `GetLength` and allow overriding?**

### Background

There is an abstract `Row` class whose derived types/classes represents a *type of row* and whose instance represents the actual row and its fields/data in a very simple table. Each type of row has a fixed length and the table is just a head-to-tail run of rows in a file. The `Row` class needs three methods: `Read` and `Write` methods which perform their obvious function on a stream given an offset, and a `GetLength` method which returns the fixed length of the type of row.

Now the user may extend my `Row` class and provide implementations for `Read`, `Write` and `GetLength` for his or her specific *row type*, and fields and properties to be used in his or her specific *row instance*. For example, the `SomeUserRow` class may have a 32-bit integer field and a single byte field, a fixed length of 5 bytes and corresponding read and write method implementation.

### The methods

#### Read

An obvious factory method, related to the type and therefore I would define it in the class itself. I'd make it `static`, but then it cannot be overridden. Then I could make it `protected abstract` and create a static generic `Read<T>` method to call it, as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1380087/146622). But I also need to be able to call this method from my code without knowing the type of the user implemented class. I can't just call `Row.Read<UserType>()` because I don't know about the user's types yet.

#### Write

A possible instance method, because most people want to write an existing `Row` to the stream. But having `Read` static, it seems weird to make `Write` an instance method.

#### GetLength

Not a factory method, but still related to the type. Again, I would make it static but this prevents overriding. I can choose to make it an instance method, which *can* be overridden but it feels wrong to do that in an Object Oriented environment: creating an instance just to get a value which does not depend on the instance (`int length = new T().GetLength()`) but rather on its type.

I have also been thinking about moving the three methods out of the classes into a separate class, but that still does not address the overriding. Or to have a class which keeps a list or dictionary of delegates pointing to the correct methods. It does not allow for *real* overriding (replacing a method pointer in a delegate array is not what I'd consider *true* overriding) and it moves the type specific methods away from the type which I think is not good from a developers point of view: having two or more places to change when you just want to change the type.

Via reflection it is possible to call the correct static method on a type, but as I was reading many rows, I found it to be too slow.

Comment: "An obvious factory method, related to the type and therefore I would define it in the class itself."  That is where you made the wrong turn.  If it's a factory method, it should belong in a factory class and it should be an instance method that can overridden by subclassing factories.

Comment: I'm confused by: "replacing a function pointer is not what I'd consider overriding" - why do you say that? That's *exactly* what overriding is: filling in at runtime the contents of a hidden "slot" that contains a function pointer. That's how overriding is implemented. If you want to have your own overriding logic that differs from the overriding semantics provided by the language then what else would you do other than implementing it via changing the contents of a slot that contains a function pointer?

Comment: By the way, as a side-comment, I think the `Write()` method should be an instance method on the row type. I know what you mean when you say it “seems weird” (it feels inconsistent, doesn’t it?) but it’s really the right approach.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I meant that asking the user to put a method pointer in an array located somewhere, pointing to the user's new method is not what I'd consider _true_ overriding. I have modified the question.

Comment: @Timwi, out of curiosity, why do you think it is the right approach to put symmetric behavior (read/write) in unrelated classes?  IMO, the entire behavior of reading and writing is encapsulated behavior external to the class and doesn't belong there.

Comment: @Kirk: Because I don’t think the behaviour *is* symmetric. Especially not in his case where the `Read` method generates a new instance and the `Write` method works on an existing instance — I think that is a pretty clear asymmetry. This is not a technical reason but a matter of opinion and you are welcome to disagree with it.

Comment: @Timwi, appreciate the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should make a `IRowReader` interface, with a `Read` method. Then you can have multiple implementations of this, which returns `Row` (or a subclass if needed, which can then override `Write` or `GetLength`).

In other words, you need a factory type, which contain the method, that you need to override. As you stated, you cannot override a static method in C#.

Then of course the question is, how do you obtain the correct IRowReader instance ? That depends on the application, but you could have your client initialize it at startup or some other well-defined point in the application; or you could use [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to have it injected and configurable.

Comment: GetLength() should probably be in the IRowReader as well (since it's especially useful when figuring out how much of the stream to read).  Furthermore, I'd be inclined to put the Write() method in there as well and rename it to IRowProcessor or something.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem too, and it is frustrating that there is no “clean” solution. Here is a workaround that I used, maybe you will like it.

Let’s assume you have a hierarchy with `Row` as the base class.

```
public class Row { }
public class DerivedRow : Row { }
```

Create another hierarchy that parallels this one, but base it on an abstract base class called `Factory`.

```
public abstract class Factory {
    public abstract Row Read(Stream stream);
    public abstract int GetLength();
}
public class RowFactory : Factory {
    public override Row Read(Stream stream) { /* read a base row */ }
    public override int GetLength() { return /* length of base row */ }
}
public class DerivedRowFactory : Factory {
    public override Row Read(Stream stream) { /* read a derived row */ }
    public override int GetLength() { return /* length of derived row */ }
}
```

Now you can write methods that take a factory as a type parameter, e.g.

```
public IEnumerable<Row> ReadRows<TRowFactory>(Stream stream)
    where TRowFactory : Factory, new()
{
    var factory = new TRowFactory();
    var numRows = stream.Length / factory.GetLength();
    for (long i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        yield return factory.Read(stream);
}

// Example call...
var rowsInFile = ReadRows<DerivedRowFactory>(File.Open(...));
```

Comment: But then I will need to know the name of the user created (factory) type in advance.

Comment: @Virtlink: Obviously you will need to know the type *at some point*. I don’t know the rest of your code, so I can only guess! How do you determine what type of row to read? No matter how you do that, you can then pass it into `ReadRows` (even if as a `Type` object instead of a generic type parameter).

Answer (score 0):

I guess abstract base class (RowBase)and a factory classes would solve this. You can identify which type of derived class you are interested in by using a configuration file or something. Basically you are using the Strategy Pattern here.

Answer (score 0):

One possible strategy is to use a static method that you will discover via Reflection. You only need to write the Reflection code once, fortunately.

Let’s assume you have a hierarchy with static `Read` and `GetLength` methods:

```
public class Row {
    public static Row Read(Stream stream) { /* read a base row */ }
    public static int GetLength() { return /* length of base row */ }
}
public class DerivedRow : Row {
    public static DerivedRow Read(Stream stream) { /* read a derived row */ }
    public static int GetLength() { return /* length of derived row */ }
}
```

Now you can write a utility function that will read a row of any type:

```
public static class RowUtils
{
    public static Row Read<T>(Stream stream) where T : Row
    {
        var method = typeof(T).GetMethod("Read",
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (method == null || !typeof(Row).IsAssignableFrom(method.ReturnType))
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(
                "Static Read method on type “{0}” does not exist or " +
                "has the wrong return type.", typeof(T).FullName));

        return (Row) method.Invoke(null, new object[] { stream });
    }
}
```

The same of course for `GetLength()`. Then you can write methods that take a row type as a type parameter, e.g.

```
public IEnumerable<Row> ReadRows<TRow>(Stream stream)
    where TRow : Row
{
    var numRows = stream.Length / RowUtils.GetLength<TRow>();
    for (long i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        yield return RowUtils.Read<TRow>(stream);
}

// Example call...
var rowsInFile = ReadRows<DerivedRow>(File.Open(...));
```

Comment: You are correct, and I have tried it, but it was too slow when reading many rows. I have updated my question to include this.

Comment: @Virtlink: Of course it would be slow the way I wrote it, because it keeps searching for the method over and over. Have you tried optimising it? You could use `Delegate.CreateDelegate()` to turn the `MethodInfo` into a delegate, and then you could cache it in a dictionary keyed by type.